# Is it possible to run a SAS or R script from PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, r, plsql, sas

Any idea to run those kind of scripts from Oracle PL/SQL? Any solution would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it is more often the other way around, calling the database from SAS or R. There is a interface for Oracle in a SAS data management product, have seen SAS salesmen boasting about how  tables in the database can be treated as any other table in SAS (but that was an additional software package to the base SAS). In R you have several options; [general ODBC connection](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html), [specific Oracle database interface](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/index.html) and [convenient tools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracleUI/index.html), and [Oracle them selves](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/datawarehouse/saternos-r-161569.html) have been providing interfaces in R for [Oracle data mining](http://cran.fhcrc.org/web/packages/RODM/index.html). Don't know about Oracle calling R directly though I have seen [such an project for PostgresSQL](http://www.omegahat.org/RSPostgres/).

Comment: Yes, I know that. Oracle provides interfaces for SAS and R (ROracle package) but I need the opposit direction. I have the logic in Oracle, have several PL/SQL stored procs and some scripts in SAS and R. I need to run those scripts also.

Answer (score 0):

Try the DBMS_SCHEDULER package - to schedule the OS/SAS script to run as a job.
http://www.oradev.com/dbms_scheduler.jsp
and
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=414652